# Zimbra 7.2 OSE Mail Queue Disappeared

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, zimbra

**System Info:**

```
Description: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Linux mail 2.6.32-42-server #95-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 25 16:10:49 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

H/W path          Device      Class      Description
====================================================
                              system     Bochs
/0                            bus        Motherboard
/0/0                          memory     96KiB BIOS
/0/401                        processor  QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.0.50
/0/402                        processor  CPU
/0/1000                       memory     2GiB System Memory
/0/1000/0                     memory     2GiB DIMM RAM
/0/100                        bridge     440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
/0/100/1                      bridge     82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
/0/100/1.1        scsi1       storage    82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
/0/100/1.1/0.0.0  /dev/cdrom  disk       DVD reader
/0/100/1.2                    bus        82371SB PIIX3 USB [Natoma/Triton II]
/0/100/1.3                    bridge     82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
/0/100/2                      display    GD 5446
/0/100/a                      storage    Virtio block device
/0/100/12                     network    Virtio network device
/1                eth0        network    Ethernet interface
```

I accidentally installed Postfix from APT onto our Zimbra email server virtual machine (KVM/Proxmox VE 2.1). I purged it instantly, however, it did not help. The following are the steps I took in a desperate attempt to fix it:

- Reinstalled Zimbra
- Stopped Zimbra service
- Reset permissions

  chown -R zimbra:zimbra /opt/zimbra
- Fixed permissions

  /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmfixperms -verbose -extended
- Restarted Zimbra service
- Renewed the Zimbra SSH keys

  zmsshkeygen
- Updated Zimbra SSH keys

  zmupdateauthkeys

Following the steps above, Zimbra now works again, the problem is that all the emails that were in the mail queue from a whole day of broken Zimbra, are now GONE! And I don't just mean that you can't see them in the GUI, they're not even on the file system anymore.

There were at least 75 emails that were in the queue when I attempted to fix Zimbra, and this is the state of the spool now:

```
zimbra@mail:~$ postqueue -p
Mail queue is empty
```

**Where the heck did all my emails go!?**

Comment: You're sure Zimbra's postfix didn't just deliver them out after startup? 75 messages is not many.

Comment: Also, while `tree` is cute and all, you'd be better severed with `su - zimbra -c "postqueue -p"`

Comment: @84104 See revisions to OP.

Comment: @84104 There were over 50 emails from my monitoring server that were directed to my email address, and they never showed up...

Comment: You'll have to process zimbra's mail log. Under RHEL, it's `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: @84104 I found them in the mail log, now how do I go about getting them to my inbox?

Comment: @84104 I even have a list of all the email messages in the data store that got "lost," here: http://pastebin.com/SR3z5acD  How do I go about re-inserting them into Zimbra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem in the future, this is how you repair it.  You may end up with more than a few duplicates, be that's better than losing an important email...

**To find the messages that got queued up, run:**

```
grep -iRE '<recipient_email_address>' /var/log/mail.log* | grep -i 'queued as' | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | xargs | tr ' ' '|'
```

**To find the actual email files on the file system, run:**

```
grep -iRE '<output_from_previous_command>' /opt/zimbra/store | grep -iv 'Message-Id' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | xargs
```

**"Inject" email back to the user account they came from:**

```
su -l zimbra

/opt/zimbra/bin/zmlmtpinject <output_from_previous_command> -r <recipient_email>
```

Keep in mind that you will lose all date/time information. The only way around that is by adding an "X-Zimbra-Received" header to each message containing a copy of the "Date:" header.  Use your imagination for how to do this, Perl comes to mind...